# Avoid rendering of specific .md files from blogdown::serve_site()

Tags: r, r-markdown, hugo, blogdown

I have a file located at

`content/post/data_for_posts/my_file.md`

I have it there because it's quite easy to do `htmltools::includeMarkdown("data_for_posts/my_file.md")` and recycle this file in different posts.

My problem is that when I `serve_site()` this creates a `public/post/data_for_posts/index.html`, which means, it gets posted to my website (as a January 1 of 0001). I guess I could change the date to year 10000, but I would rather handle it the way I handle the `.Rmd` and other files, as suggested [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/configuration.html#fn25)

I have tried to modify my `config.toml` but have not managed to solve the issue.

```
ignoreFiles = ["\\.Rmd$", "\\.Rmarkdown$", "_files$", "_cache$", "content/post/data_for_posts/my_file.md"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple techniques that I use to do this:

1. Rename `data_for_posts/my_file.md` so it uses a file extension that hugo does not interpret as a known markup language, for example change `.md` to `.markd` or `mdn`.[*]
2. Rename `data_for_posts/my_file.md` so it includes a string that you will never use in a real content file, for example `data_for_posts-UNPUBLISHED/my_file.md`. Then add that string (`UNPUBLISHED` or whatever) to your config `ignoreFiles` list.[**]

[*] In the `content/` directory, a file with one of the following file extensions will be interpreted by hugo as containing a known markup language: .ad, .adoc, .asciidoc, .htm, .html, .markdown, .md, .mdown, .mmark, .pdc, .pandoc, .org, or .rst (this is an excerpt of [something](https://www.ii.com/hugo-markup-languages/) I wrote).

[**] The strings listed in `ignoreFiles` seem to be case sensitive so I like to use all-upper-case characters in my ignored file names (because I never use upper-case chars in real content file names). Also note that there is no need to specify the path and my experience is that path delimiters (`/` or `\`) cause problems.

Comment: The `UNPUBLISHED` hack seems to be working, it's quite confusing why other ways don't but I will stick to this for the time being (already past diminishing returns on effort here)

Comment: I have spent a lot of time trying to get a string like your `content/post/data_for_posts/my_file.md` to be recognized as a Go Template regular expression, including using `//`, `///`, and `\/` to try to escape the path delimiter which seems to have a special meaning in Go regular expressions. Maybe we should cross post this question to [go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go) or [go-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/go-templates) or somewhere Go experts hang out. Also people in [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) might know...

Comment: Another thought: I think the `content` part of a path should not be specified because `ignoreFiles` only works on files in `content` so I bet that is built in and if you specify it Hugo will look for `content/content`

Comment: And another thought: I am on Windows so what I've really tried to ignore are strings like `post\data_for_posts\my_file.md` (using backslash (\\) as the path delimiter). It's possible this is easier on a system where the path delimiter is slash (/).

Comment: @n m Good thoughts, I'm on Ubuntu so it is probably not related to (\ vs /)